# Inno Setup - prompt user that {app} folder not empty after uninstall?

Tags: file, inno-setup, prompt, uninstallation

I have an Inno Setup script that requires the user to copy some files into the application directory (because the files are copyrighted and I can't distribute them with my installer).

When the uninstaller runs, it of course does not delete those user-copied files or the folders that contain them.

How can I prompt the user that the files and folders still exist and that they should be deleted by hand?

I know how to modify the UninstalledAll message that appears after the uninstall is finished, but I want to be able to show a special message if files actually remain uninstalled.

Comment: If you know what they're called, you can tell Inno to remove them as well, if you want to.  Otherwise (provided that the folder did not exist at the time of the first install) Inno should already show a warning that some files were not removed.

Comment: Thanks for this. In fact Inno doesn't display a warning that some files were not removed. It simply doesn't remove them. The folders that contain the files were created by the installer itself, so I'm not sure where to turn next. I can't know the exact names of the newly created files, so it would be good to be able to list any files found in a folder or subfolders. I'll keep looking and will report back if I find anything.